# Git plug-in with Jenkins pipeline attaches option --force for git fetch automatically

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I noticed git-plugin behaviour is different between free style(usual) job and pipeline job.

Recently, I have been migrating jobs to pipeline. 
The git-plugin behaves followings with free style job.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress -- git@gitlabs.xxxx:xxxx/xxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=30
```

On the other hand, The git-plugin behaves followings with pipeline.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- git@gitlabs.xxxx.xxxx:xxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=30
```

With pipeline, git-plugin attaches --force option. For my job, it need the local modification a little it rarely is changed.

So I would like to remove this --force option. Is there the way to remove it?
The pipeline code of git is generated by snippet generator, the code is like this.

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, 
scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', 
branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']], browser: [$class: 'GitLab', repoUrl: 'https://gitlabs.xxxx.xxxx/xxxx.git', version: '10.8'], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: false, timeout: 30]], 
submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx', url: 'git@gitlabs.xxxx.xxxx:xxxx.git']]]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute a bat command just like this:

```
bat label: '', script: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe fetch
--no-tags --progress -- git@gitlabs.xxxx:xxxx/xxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=30'
```

but the --force command doesn't wipe your already cached repository and clone it again. The `--force` option only applies to `refspecs` which do not start with the + option.

Comment: Thank you for useful suggestion, that's Egg of Columbus I'll try that way. Maybe the way which is realized by scm class doesn't exist.